# Is there a way to increase the indentation size of PHP's DOMDocument formatOutput property?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

Is there a way to increase the indentation size of PHP's DOMDocument formatOutput property?  Right now it indents each node 2 spaces.  I would like to make it either a tab or 4 spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be possible to change the indentation string in [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/), but to my knowledge you cannot alter the indentation DOM uses. It's possible for [XMLWriter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-set-indent-string.php) though.

As an alternative, you could use Tidy to prettyprint the XML:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = TRUE;
$dom->loadXml('<root><foo><bar>   baz   </bar></foo></root>');
$tidy = tidy_parse_string($dom->saveXml(), array(
    'indent' => TRUE,
    'input-xml' => TRUE,
    'output-xml' => TRUE,
    'add-xml-space' => FALSE,
    'indent-spaces' => 4
));
$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo $tidy;
```

but note that this behaves quirky in the above case. It removes the spaces in the bar element unless you slap an `xml:space="preserve"` on the bar tag. When you do that it will keep the spaces but also put newlines before and after. You have to fiddle with it to see if it fits your problem. See [Tidy docs](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/tidy_man.html#DETAILED%20CONFIGURATION%20OPTIONS)

Comment: Is there any way to change this somewhere in a configuration file?  It doesn't have to be at run-time.

Comment: @Thinking To my knowledge there is no way to configure this from PHP.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't a very nice solution because it depends on knowing that the format is prefixed with double spaces:

```
preg_replace_callback('/^( +)</m', function($a) { 
  return str_repeat(' ',intval(strlen($a[1]) / 2) * 4).'<';  
}, $doc->saveXML());
```

It replaces each indentation with 4 spaces. Or you could remove the `*4` and use `"\n"` as the repeating character.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed to change the 2 space indent to tabs, changed the return to this: `return str_repeat("\t",intval(strlen($a[1]) / 2)).'<';`