# preg_replace Double Spaces to tab (\t) at the beginning of a line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Just a Simple Quick Question.
I want to replace the Double Spaces at the begenning of the line by Tabs.
Currently I am trying with  `preg_replace('~^( {2})~', "\t", $text)` but that replaces only the first occurrence of Double Space.

--EDIT--

```
preg_replace('~PATTERN~', "REPLACEMENT", "      HalloWorld")
//Should be equal to "\t\t\tHallo World"
```

Comment: Can you please show us a sample of your text, as were getting a little confused as of exactly what you require !

Comment: @RobertPitt: I think if there are more than two spaces, e.g. 4, then those should be replaced by two tabs.

Comment: @user256007: Can you see if my updated answer does what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use \G escape sequence for that:

```
$var = '    Hello    World'; //x4 spaces
echo preg_replace("/\G {2}/","\t",$var);
```

\G marks the location of the end of the previous match (or the beginning of the string for the first match); that way, all matches after the first one try to consume additional two spaces from the character previous match left off.

Comment: +1 That is totally awesome, I knew it was somehow possible with a simple `preg_replace()`. `\G` is called an [escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) though, not a modifier.

Comment: Thanks. It Works. But preg_replace() is greedy by Nature. Then why it didn't work without `\G`?

Comment: Oh! I never thought it would be that easy.. just removing the `()` makes it work.

Comment: @user256007: It will have the same effect without the `\G`, but it will also replace double spaces anywhere *else* in the string, not just the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

Testing and wortking:

```
$var = '  Hello World'; //x2 spaces

echo preg_replace("/^ {2}(.*)$/","\t$1",$var);
```

---

Edit

Felix has the force with this one!

```
echo preg_replace('~(?<![^\s]{2})  ~', "\t",$var);
```

Comment: That also only replaces the first occurrence of double spaces.

Comment: But it doesn't work if it has multiple spaces before Hello World

Comment: The OP's question is a little hard to figure out exactly what he wants, iv'e asked him to update with sample text.

Comment: Unfortunately my regex fails when more than two spaces are between words or at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace more than one occurrence of double-spaces with tabs, try this:

```
function spaces_to_tabs($m) {
    return str_repeat("\t", strlen($m[1]) / 2);
}

$text = preg_replace_callback('~^((?: {2})+)~', 'spaces_to_tabs', $text);
```

If your text is multiline, add the `m` modifier to your regex so it considers `^` as the start boundary after a newline character (for each line in your string):

```
~^((?: {2})+)~m
```

Comment: Nope. Tried and not working. and $text is not multiline string at all.

Comment: @Felix Kling: I used a callback with `str_repeat()`. I'm not sure if it's possible to repeat capture backreferences without a callback :/

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution without PREG functions.

Let us say we have a `$str = "    My Text";`

I needed an aux variable to store an integer:

```
$tmp = strlen($str) - strlen(ltrim($t3)); // If ltrim is not ok for you
                                          // You can use preg_replace()
$tmp = str_repeat("\t", $tmp / 2 /* 2 spaces -> 1 tab */) . ltrim($t3);
```

The PREG function is more elegant, but I'm not sure of how efficient it is

Comment: http://codepad.org/UN6xZkB0 in codepad zeuscg's solution seems faster. The same code on a borrowed computer that I am now outputs: `ssice's method needed 1.89608502388 seconds. zeuxcg's, 1.9418430328369` so it will depend on optimizations during compilation. This PC's PHP is `PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.1 w/ Suhosin patch (cli)`

Comment: You didn't say you needed it that way :)

Answer (score 0):

From another questions answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4349514/778669

If it is for XML from a DOMDocument which uses 2 spaces to indent:

```
$var = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <node>
    <anothernode>some    text</anothernode>
  </node>
</root>';

echo preg_replace_callback('/^( +)</m', function($a) { 
  return str_repeat("\t",intval(strlen($a[1]) / 2)).'<';  
}, $var);
```

Will replace every double space indent at the start of the line with a tab.

So the result would be (substituting X for tab):

```
$var = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
X<node>
XX<anothernode>some    text</anothernode>
X</node>
</root>';
```

And the double spaces inside the xml will be left intact.

Answer (score 0):

Proper solution

```
preg_replace('/^ {2}|\G {2}/Sm', "\t", $text)
```

Replace first 2 spaces on the line `^ {2}` and then every two  spaces that follow the last successful replacement `\G {2}`. `\G` is last replacement and `/S` is optimized replace as we are going to replace more occurrences at once and `/m` treat it as multi-line string.

At the end it will ignore all spaces if they are not at the beginning of the line which I understood was the point, right?