# Regex to convert spaces to tabs, but only at the beginning of a line

Tags: regex, tabs, coding-style, replace, space

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530931/preg-replace-double-spaces-to-tab-t-at-the-beginning-of-a-line), the top answer (`/\G {2}/`) works perfectly for one line, but I can't get it working multi-line.

It needs to convert 2 spaces to tabs, but only at the beginning of the line. Here's an example: http://pastebin.com/4LQ3FUAs

Any help would be appreciated, got a whole project to convert over...

Comment: use `^` to match beginning of a line

Comment: @Sergio ^ doesn't work with `\G` because `\G` is telling it to either start from the beginning OR at the end of the last match, which is why it will keep the indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a regular expression that I could use on a whole file at a time, so I created a little script to recursively iterate through a directory and change each line of each php / js / css file individually, runs very fast though. Just cd to your directory and run the script.

```
<?php
$dir   = getcwd();
$it    = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
$ii    = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it);
$files = new RegexIterator($ii, '#^(?:[A-Z]:)?(?:/(?!\.Trash)[^/]+)+/[^/]+\.(?:php|css|js)$#Di');

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    $name   = $file->getPath().'/'.$file->getFileName();
    echo $name."\n";
    $lines  = file($file->getPath().'/'.$file->getFileName());
    $length = count($lines);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i)
    {
        $lines[$i] = preg_replace('/\G {2}/', "\t", $lines[$i]);
    }
    file_put_contents($name, implode('', $lines));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is probably better, but here's a pure regex version:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?:\G|^) {2}/m', "\t", $subject);
```

`^` in multiline mode allows it to match the first pair of spaces in the line, then `\G` chains any subsequent matches in that line to the first one.